# jQuery snippet stops page from working but doesn't throw error

Tags: javascript, jquery

The moment I uncomment the code below, the alert(1) does not run, and all my jQuery plugins etc etc are not working. The commented out code does an Ajax form submit. The Chrome console is not showing any errors

```
 $('.ui-page-active .image-upload').change(function() {
        alert(1);

        // $('.ui-page-active #image-upload-form').ajaxSubmit(function() {
        //     beforeSend: function() {
        //         console.log('beforeSend');
        //         // status.empty();
        //         // var percentVal = '0%';
        //         // bar.width(percentVal)
        //         // percent.html(percentVal);
        //     },
        //     uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        //         var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        //         console.log(percentVal);
        //     },
        //     complete: function(xhr) {
        //         console.log(xhr.responseText);
        //     },
        //     error: function() {
        //         alert('error');
        //     }
        // });

    });
```

Comment: I don't see where this has anything to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.ui-page-active #image-upload-form').ajaxSubmit(function() {
            beforeSend: function() {
```

`ajaxSubmit` does not take a function as a parameter but an object.  This shoudl be:

```
$('.ui-page-active #image-upload-form').ajaxSubmit({
         beforeSend: function() {
```

Comment: Aw thanks! 8 mins til I can accept your answer. My chrome console is taking strain from the Facebook SDK, a whole lot of strange 'iFrame this and that' errors (my next SO question), so maybe that is why it died silently?

Comment: Dammit, don't ask me why I passed in a function and thought it was an object literal, I was still checking that my object literal had valid syntax :)